# How to get the Metadata of songs played in MusicPlayer in Qml

Tags: qt, qml, audio-player

I am trying to get and display the `metaData.coverArtUrlSmall` from a mp3 file in qml. Song is playing fine but the metadata is not printing

I tried something like this

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: player
    onSourceChanged:
    {
        console.log("graphic " +metaData.coverArtUrlSmall);

    }
}
```

It prints qml: graphic **undefined**

Is there any way we could get the metadata of songs in qml

Comment: According to the [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediametadata.html) not all identifiers are supported on all platforms. Can you maybe try print the title or another metadata field to see if you get anything ?

Comment: @Blabbouze I tried metaData.albumArtist, metaData.title, metaData.size
unfortunately everything prints undefined.

Comment: Oh maybe it's because the media is not loaded yet when `onSourceChanged`is called. Try to print metaData.title in `onStatusChanged`instead (after checking that `status` is equal to [MediaPlayer.Loaded](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html#status-prop)).

Comment: @Blabbouze Tried with both onStatusChanged and onStopped still the same result

Comment: If you try to do something like `console.log(metaData)` does it says it's undefined ? If so try this : `console.log(player.metaData)`

Comment: I tried like that earlier like , console.log("artist",player.metaData.albumArtist)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, in order to get metadata information, a `metaData` object is needed, for which the `onMetaDataChanged` is guaranteed to report back meta data information. Looking at sample code, this needs to be:

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: player
    metaData.onMetaDataChanged:
    {
        console.log("graphic " +metaData.coverArtUrlSmall);

    }
}
```