# QML mediaplayer does not show metaData for mp3 streams

Tags: qt, qml, metadata, media-player, audio-streaming

Given the following code:

```
Item {
   id: mainPage
   anchors.fill: parent

   function getMetaData(metaData) {
         var text = ""

         text += "title: " + metaData.title + "\n"
         text += "subTitle: " + metaData.subTitle + "\n"
         text += "author: " + metaData.author + "\n"
         text += "comment: " + metaData.comment + "\n"
         text += "description: " + metaData.description + "\n"
         text += "category: " + metaData.category + "\n"
         text += "genre: " + metaData.genre + "\n"
         text += "language: " + metaData.language + "\n"
         text += "albumTitle: " + metaData.albumTitle + "\n"
         text += "albumArtist: " + metaData.albumArtist + "\n"
         text += "coverArtUrlSmall: " + metaData.coverArtUrlSmall + "\n"
         text += "coverArtUrlLarge: " + metaData.coverArtUrlLarge + "\n"
         text += "posterUrl: " + metaData.posterUrl + "\n"

      return text
   }

   MediaPlayer {
      id: audioPlayer
      audioRole: MusicRole
      source:      "https://s3-webradio.antenne.de/antenne/stream/mp3?aw_0_1st.playerid=radio.de"
      //source: "https://swr-swr3-live.cast.addradio.de/swr/swr3/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3"
      //source: "http://bob.hoerradar.de/radiobob-hartesaite-mp3-hq?sABC=5r65511s%230%23os634o21s23sr4751opp80560p2o2sr6%23fgernzf.enqvbobo.qr&amsparams=playerid:streams.radiobob.de;skey:1583698207"

      onPlaybackStateChanged: {
         console.log("State: " + audioPlayer.status + " Meta data: \n" + getMetaData(audioPlayer.metaData));
      }
   }
}
```

The audio streams I have tried will playback just fine. However I am unable to retrieve meta data for the streams. E.g. title, artist, and so on. All of the meta fields will just be "undefined".

I have tried several streams, none would show any meta data. Yet I am sure the stream provides those infos, since other player applications will show title, artist, etc.

I have tried other approaches (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139046/how-to-get-the-metadata-of-songs-played-in-musicplayer-in-qml)), but still I don't get any metadata.

I am on ubuntu touch, if that matters, and app armor policies are `["audio", "networking"]` (also tried `music_files_read`, didn't help).

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget some little things:

1.`audioRole: MediaPlayer.MusicRole`

2. `mainPage.getMetaData(audioPlayer.metaData));` you should call mainPage id and then call its function.

here is correct code :

```
Item {
    id: mainPage
    anchors.fill: parent

    function getMetaData(metaData) {
        var text = ""

        text += "title: " + metaData.title + "\n"
        text += "subTitle: " + metaData.subTitle + "\n"
        text += "author: " + metaData.author + "\n"
        text += "comment: " + metaData.comment + "\n"
        text += "description: " + metaData.description + "\n"
        text += "category: " + metaData.category + "\n"
        text += "genre: " + metaData.genre + "\n"
        text += "language: " + metaData.language + "\n"
        text += "albumTitle: " + metaData.albumTitle + "\n"
        text += "albumArtist: " + metaData.albumArtist + "\n"
        text += "coverArtUrlSmall: " + metaData.coverArtUrlSmall + "\n"
        text += "coverArtUrlLarge: " + metaData.coverArtUrlLarge + "\n"
        text += "posterUrl: " + metaData.posterUrl + "\n"

        return text
    }


    MediaPlayer {
        id: audioPlayer
        audioRole: MediaPlayer.MusicRole
        source:      "https://s3-webradio.antenne.de/antenne/stream/mp3?aw_0_1st.playerid=radio.de"
        //source: "https://swr-swr3-live.cast.addradio.de/swr/swr3/live/mp3/128/stream.mp3"
        //source: "http://bob.hoerradar.de/radiobob-hartesaite-mp3-hq?sABC=5r65511s%230%23os634o21s23sr4751opp80560p2o2sr6%23fgernzf.enqvbobo.qr&amsparams=playerid:streams.radiobob.de;skey:1583698207"

        metaData.onMetaDataChanged: {
            console.log("State: " + audioPlayer.status + " Meta data: \n" + mainPage.getMetaData(audioPlayer.metaData));
        }
    }



}
```

here is out put :

[image]

**As you see in this picture it shows `genre: Pop`**

I test another music from [this site](https://www.jamendo.com) and print another metadata , undefined means that the source doesn't have this metaData .

Comment: Okay so for me it displays "undefined" for all fields, including "genre" for the first stream. At least the third stream ("http://bob.hoerradar.de...") *must* also provide title/artist as it is displayed when running in another player.

So I guess this might be a Ubuntu Touch issue then.

Comment: maybe QT version , I use ubuntu too. and I use Qt 5.14.0, and I have windows too , I will test it here and tell in to you

Comment: I am using **Ubuntu Touch** (on the phone), not ubuntu desktop.

Comment: oh,so I don't know :)