# qml video metadata: undefined. get video file information

Tags: android, c++, qt, video, qml

i wanna take video metadata but i have a problem

code:

```
          Video
               {
                   id: videoList
                   anchors.left: parent.Left
                   width: 110
                   height: 80
                   autoLoad: true
                   muted: true
                   volume: 0.4
                   fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                   source: "file://" + root.files[modelData]

                   Component.onCompleted:
                   {
                       videoList.seek(1000)
                       print("Size: " + videoList.metaData.resolution)
                   }
                }
```

output:

qml: Size: undefined

please help me to solve this. thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QML mediaplayer does not show metaData for mp3 streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428717/qml-mediaplayer-does-not-show-metadata-for-mp3-streams)

Comment: @Parisa.H.R salam, no i did that but undefined is still there

Comment: so your file hasn't metadata info. share your File in question too.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R my file is .mp4 and i can show this in my application in android device. i think must be there some info like size . but i can't get anything

Comment: @Parisa.H.R i taked all .mp4 files in device but all are undefined . my english is still bad, sorry for that

Comment: please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can run and test it.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R `Video
                    {
                        id: videoList
                        anchors.left: parent.Left
                        width: 95
                        height: 65
                        autoPlay: true
                        muted: true
                        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
                        source: ""  }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to wait until the video has finished loading by checking its status. Try adding this to your Video object:

```
 onStatusChanged: {
     if (status == MediaPlayer.Loaded) {
         print("Size: " + videoList.metaData.resolution)
     }
 }
```

Comment: i tested this and i under stood that never not will be loaded ummm really confusing. see this `onStatusChanged:
                        {
                            print("******* Status Changed *******")
                            if (videoList.status == MediaPlayer.Loaded)
                            {
                                print("Size: " + videoList.metaData.resolution)
                            }
                        }` and says status changed but not will be enter in our if

Comment: Please don't try to write large blocks of code in a comment. It's not readable. You can add an update to your post if you want.

Comment: i am new. im sorry. ok

Comment: i edited my post. is that ok?. but i cant see that edit

Comment: I don't see your edit. But anyway, try printing out the actual value of `status`. Maybe you're not getting the `Loaded` status because the loading is failing? (In other words, it could be a bad video.)

Comment: my file works ok, i think that maybe must be there a permission for get metadata from them, i just have READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I still recommend seeing what the actual status value is.

Comment: i have one file for run and i got 2 status changed ONE - qml: ******* Status Changed ******* qml: Status: 6 and TWO - qml: ******* Status Changed ******* qml: Status: 7

Comment: status: 6 means  the media has buffered data. and status 7 is  the media has played to the end. so where is loaded ): ?